# CURL execution returns empty response and shows

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL in my project, Its working fine locally but if i use the
same code its not executing, I tried to debug it. The output as follows :

```
Took 0 seconds to send a request to https://www.google.co.in
```

I used the following sample code:

```
$handle=curl_init('https://www.google.co.in');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$content = curl_exec($handle);

if(!curl_errno($handle))
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($handle);

    echo '<br/> Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
}
else
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($handle);
}

echo $content;
```

The Problem is in server, I don't know what to enable in php.ini.

Please note that in server CURL and SSL is enabled.  If anyone faced similar problems, share solutions please.

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: nope .. I did not get any error message

Comment: Can you move down the curl_error function from else part.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Comment: and have you tried another website than google ? Have you tried with HTTP ? Are errors reporting enabled ?

Comment: yes.. I tried with HTTP and HTTPS nothing worked..and also moved the error no code outside if statement.. nothing happen.

Comment: if(curl_errno($handle))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($handle);
}

Comment: yes Got it .. Got the error : curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons.. Checked php info curl_exec has disabled..

Comment: Have you manually tried command-line `curl https://www.google.co.in` and is there is a proxy server blocking it?

Comment: Curl_exec is disabled... Is there any way to enable using htaccess with out php.ini ?

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint You can't, you have to edit php.ini, here's a [list](http://www.uk1.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PROBLEM:
>
> Function `curl_exec` is disabled. What to do?
>
> SOLUTION:
>
> In order to eliminate this error message you need to do **one** of the following things:
>
> 1. Remove the `curl_exec` string from the `disable_functions` in the `php.ini` file
> 2. Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don’t have an access to the `php.ini` file
> 3. Change hosting provider to one which allows the running of the `curl_exec` function.
>
> Here is an example of the entry in `php.ini`.
>
> Change from:
>
> `disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,show_source,eval,posix_getpwuid`
>
> To:
>
> `disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_multi_exec,show_source,eval,posix_getpwuid`

Source: http://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/?p=1365

Comment: Soryy..For the time being, i just copied that from the above link.

Comment: Yes I done that... Now working.. We cant enable curl_exec using .htaccess only using php.ini

Answer (score 9):

For me in this case, the problem was that I was getting a 302 redirect rather than the actual get request.

After turning on `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26611776/327074)

```
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
```

I got the following in the `errorlog.txt`:

```
* Connected to www.example.com (X.X.X.X) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=COMODO SSL; CN=www.example.com
*        start date: 2016-04-28 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2018-04-08 23:59:59 GMT
*        issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /path/to/file.php
HTTP/1.1^M
Host: www.example.com^M
Accept: */*^M
^M
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found^M
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx^M
< Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2016 02:06:45 GMT^M
< Content-Type: text/html^M
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked^M
< Connection: keep-alive^M
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19^M
< Location: https://www.example.com/other/url/^M
< ^M
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
```

N.B.

1. `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` (should just be a 200 response)
2. `Location: https://www.example.com/other/url/` is different from the `GET` request URL

Comment: For me I found in this log : Unable to initialize NSS. I just restarted both nginx and php-fpm and it worked... 2 hours for just this :)